# Beat Frequencies in EM Radiation

Tags: radiation

Is it possible for a very low beat frequency (say 10-40 Hz) to arise from the interference between a radio or microwave signal to an electronic device for example, and EMR emitted from the same device; and therefore in principle capable of interacting with 'brain waves' of comparable frequency (10-40 Hz)?

Comment: If you look up hyperphysics.com, the beat phenomenon should be covered, but I think (/completely guess) you might be thinking of the auditory delta waves used on some audio tracks. These are not beats per se, I would be cautious in making any connection to "brain waves". Sorry, I am guessing as to your specific question. But do look up brain waves on Wikipedia as to the biological details.

Comment: The ~10-40 Hz range would correspond to an extremely long wavelength (i.e., ~7.5-30 Mm) mode if it were free (i.e., not coupled to the medium in which it propagates) electromagnetic radiation.  My guess is that the probability of that interacting with your head which is much less than one meter is extremely small.

Comment: The effect imagined is certainly analogous to binaural 'beat effects'--and there's an article in 'Frontiers of Psychiatry' about the effects of 'auditory beat stimulation'--, but would derive from an actual interference between EMR frequencies implying a 'beat' of the same magnitude as 'alpha' brain waves themselves. From a clinical point of view, any such effect must be presumed significant, and researched. My inquiry therefore is primarily whether the disparity between input and output EMR associated with electronic devices, computers in particular, could result in such an EMR beat effect.

Comment: Yes, that is really the issue isn't it: whether frequency per se, especially around 10 Hz, is critical or not.  One might equally speculate about the wavelengths of 'brain waves' were it imaginable that these somehow defined spatial contexts of 'resonance' over distances of the order implied by their frequencies. Fascinating, don't you think.

Comment: The electromagnetic signals in the brain pass through what are effectively a lot of capacitors (i.e., your neurons) and the cumulative effect can be measured as what you call brain waves.  The point being, these are not free electromagnetic waves so the relationship between frequency and wavelength is not simple (i.e., you would need to derive a dispersion relation for the myelin sheath along the axions of neurons.  Then one would need to consider the discharge across the axion terminals to the dendrites, which again is not a free EM mode.

Comment: These are all valid points, and seem to answer the question with respect to any imagined effect, which is the gist of the inquiry anyway.  What though is actually the speed of 'brain waves'?  (Additionally--and only for the bold--, it is not inconceivably that what we are considering EM activity, ostensibly deriving in mitochondria etc., is actually only 'focused' within, or really 'as', various organisms, human and otherwise; rather than as in the usual conception exclusively originating within them, as de novo impulses propagating in and between neurones: some metaphysics for another day).

Comment: I should note that my comments do not rule out the possibility that EM radiation can affect the functioning of mammalian cells.  I was just trying to clarify that free mode EM radiation at such low frequencies almost certainly cannot even know your head exists, let alone interact with it.  This is similar to why visible light cannot be used to image atoms.

Answer (score -2):

If for example two EM waves of around 2-2.4 GHz commonly associated with 'wifi' transmission, thus with wavelengths around 12.5 to 15 cm. comparable to the dimensions of the human brain are disparate by a frequency of 10 Hz, then it is quite conceivable that the transition in their relation ostensible as a 'beat frequency' of 10 Hz will also imply an interaction, possibly deleterious, with normal cerebral 'electrical activity' measurable as 'alpha waves' of similar frequency 10 Hz.